# Printing two A5 pages on a single A4 page - configure print settings by code

Tags: c#, .net, printing, system.drawing

**Requirements**

We have a custom application (print service) that prints any document to the desired network printer.

This is done building upon:

```
System.Drawing.Printing
```

Specifically:

- PrintDocument
- PrinterSettings

The application has been running fine for some time, recently I received a change request to support the following:

> It must be possible to print A5 documents on A4 pages, in two-per-page
>   fashion

That means we have to be able to support these manual print options by code:

[image]

[image]

I would think this should be possible, I just don't know where to look.

> Can `PrintDocument` do this? If so, by which settings? Is there
>   anything else that I can use for this?

Answer (score 1):

If your current code is printing to a Graphics object, like this:

```
public void Print(Graphics g);
```

Then you should be able to squeeze in two page outputs on the same physical page like so:

```
  g.Transform = create matrix scaled to 50% and rotated 90°
  page1.Print(g);
  g.Transform = create matrix scaled to 50%, rotated 90° and translated half a page, 
  page2.Print(g);
```